# Two dimension java array

Tags: java, hex, arrays

I am super new to java and I would like to know something about the code below.

```
public Something() throws Exception
{
    byte[][] value=new byte[2][0];
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kgen.init(128); 
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    value[0]=skey.getEncoded();
    skey = kgen.generateKey();
    value[1]=skey.getEncoded();

    value[0][0]=0x12;value[0][1]=0x33;value[0][2]=0x21;
    value[1][0]=0x12;value[1][1]=0x33;value[1][2]=0x21;
}
```

1)Is it possible to create a byte array with 0 columns like that on line 3?

2)At the end how many columns and rows are created and what is the value inside them?

3)The last two lines of code assign hex values to these specific columns and rows?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible"? Do you mean is it useful? If it compiles and runs, it's possible.

Comment: Most of these questions could be answered with simple test. What happens when you try to execute this code? Is there anything which is confusing you about it?

Comment: @4castle . I mean why may someone want to do it. Besides I see that the columns are not 0. they change (value [o][1]), right?

Comment: @Pshemo you mean for example with a println? It is a part of too many lines and classes. That's why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1)Is it possible to create a byte array with 0 columns like that on line 3?

Yes.

> 2)At the end how many columns and rows are created and what is the value inside them?

At first, the array will contain 2 * 0 = 0 bytes.

Then, shortly after declaring the array you have these lines:

```
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
value[0]=skey.getEncoded();
```

This replaces the first row, which had 0 columns, with a row that has 16 columns (128 bits as per AES key spec).

Once you do that to both, it'll be as if you had declared a `byte[2][16]`.

> 3)The last two lines of code assign hex values to these specific columns and rows?

They set hex values for some of the bytes in the now 2*16 byte array, yes. The other bytes will be strongly random.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Is it possible to declare an arry with 0 columns and then change it (afterwards the columns become 16)? And do they set random hex values or the ones that are represented (x12, x21)?

Comment: You can not change the size of an array. You can only set a reference to a new array of a different size. In your example, you have an array full of array references, and each of those can be set to point to a new array (maybe giving the illusion of changing the dimensions of a 2D array, but it's really just 1D*1D). All new arrays in Java come pre-set as 0/0.0/null.

Comment: Thank you very very much